# CSS: How to account for the lost space when converting item from static to fixed/absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my `jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/vd2vstoy/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="top-banner">
        <h1>
            Some&lt;body&gt; Once Told Me
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="fixedElement">
        the <i>HelloWorld</i> is gonna roll me
    </div>
    <h1>
        I ain't the C-sharp-est tool<br>
        In the shed.
    </h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    height:1000px;
}
.top-banner  {
    background-color:yellow;
    height:200px;
}
.fixedElement {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    padding:15px;
    position:static;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){ 
    var $el = $('.fixedElement'); 
    var isPositionFixed = ($el.css('position') == 'fixed');

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 220 && !isPositionFixed) { 
        $('.fixedElement').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 220 && isPositionFixed) {
        $('.fixedElement').css({'position': 'static', 'top': '0px'}); 
    }
});
```

The point of this is so that the `fixedElement` sticks to the top when it reached that 200 pixel mark. Unfortunately, the space that the `fixedElement` was taking up goes away when it turns `fixed` position.

Is there anyway that I can preserve the space that was there so that as soon as the element becomes fixed, the rest of the content doesn't shift up and become unseen?

To see what's happening, just scroll down in the example `jsfiddle` and see what happens when the `fixedElement` div reaches the top of the screen.

Comment: give something else extra margin at the same time you switch to fixed

Comment: @dandavis I tried that, both `margin` and `padding` alike, it didn't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vd2vstoy/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I normally do is wrap the item that is going to be fixed to the top in a div that has a fixed height and remains relative. That way, when the `fixed` element is moved out of the regular flow by setting its `position: absolute` (in the scroll event), the space will be retained by the containing div, and no page-jumping occurs.

So you wrap the `.fixed-element` in a `div` of a matching height, but do not make that one change to a `position: absolute`

Here's a working snippet:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  var $el = $('.fixedElement');
  var isPositionFixed = ($el.css('position') == 'fixed');
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 220 && !isPositionFixed) {
    $('.fixedElement').css({
      'position': 'fixed',
      'top': '0px'
    });
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() < 220 && isPositionFixed) {
    $('.fixedElement').css({
      'position': 'static',
      'top': '0px'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 1000px;
}

.top-banner {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
}

.fixedElement {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  padding: 15px;
  position: static;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 25px;
}

.fixedElementWrapper {
  /* Match the height of the elements to prevent shifting */
  height: 25px;
}

h1 {
  /* Adding some space to make the effect more visible */
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="top-banner">
    <h1>
      Some&lt;body&gt; Once Told Me
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="fixedElementWrapper">
    <!-- we add this because this is gonna preserve our space -->
    <div class="fixedElement">
      The <i>HelloWorld</i> is gonna roll me

    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>
    I ain't the C-sharp-est tool<br> In the shed.
  </h1>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [updated version of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vd2vstoy/2/) with the fix.

I wrapped your fixed element in a parent wrapper, then on fixed, set the height of the parent, changing

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 220 && !isPositionFixed) { 
    $('.fixedElement').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
}
```

to

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 220 && !isPositionFixed) {
    $('.fixedElement').parent().height($('.fixedElement').outerHeight(true))
    $('.fixedElement').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'});
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful, but I didn't pick this as the answer because if the `fixedElement` has `slideToggle` set when clicked, it gets more complex to regulate the outerheight property. But hats off to you for the quickest solution!